# Redirecting output of tcl proc to file and output (like tee)

Tags: tcl

I need `redirect` that I found in one of my searches:

```
redirect -tee LogFile.log {include ../RunDemoTests.tcl}
```

Where `include` is a TCL `proc` and `../RunDemoTests.tcl` is a parameter to the proc.  Is there a library I need to be able to use redirect or is this not general tcl?

I am working in an EDA tool environment that runs under both Windows and Linux, so I need a solution that is just TCL and does not rely on something from the OS.

I have tried numerous variations of:

```
set ch [open |[list include "../OsvvmLibraries/UART/RunDemoTests.tcl"] r]
set lf [open build.log w]
puts "Starting"
puts $lf "Starting"
while {[gets $ch line]>=0} {
  puts $line
  puts $lf $line
}
close $lf
```

However, this only seems to work when the command is something from the OS environment, such as:

```
set ch [open |[list cat ../tests.pro] r]
```

Printing from this can be a significant number of lines, buffering is ok, but not collecting the whole file and then printing as the files can be long (180K lines).

Comment: It's not a standard tcl procedure, no. Where did you find mention of it?

Comment: @Shawn  Here:  https://www.micro-ip.com/STA/dictionary_306_17/redirect.html   Looks like it is a page of an eda tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to a question on comp.lang.tcl a while ago, I created a small Tcl module to provide tee-like functionality in Tcl. I have now published the code on the [Tcl wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tee).

You would use it like this:

```
package require tee
tee stdout build.log
try {
    puts "Starting"
    include ../OsvvmLibraries/UART/RunDemoTests.tcl
} finally {
    # Make sure the tee filter is always popped from the filter stack
    chan pop stdout
}
```

This assumes the `include RunDemoTests.tcl` command produces output to *stdout*.

Comment: It can be useful to use `try`/`finally` to make sure that the `tee` is popped from the channel's filter stack.

Comment: I have updated the code as per your suggestion.

Comment: This is perfect.   Will this eventually be delivered as part of a TCL release?   There is a time lag from TCL releasing something like this to the EDA tools updating their version of TCL.   I noted that I can source this file and it works well.

Comment: Is there any way to get the output line by line so I can do different filtering for each of the locations it goes to?   For example, when it goes to a file, I add HTML tags.   When it goes to the simulator output I would like it without the tags - as people complain about them.   I could do a separate post if that makes sense.

Comment: You can modify the write proc to do whatever you like. Or, based on this example, you can create another transchan that adds HTML tags. You can then push that transchan onto the channel that is returned by `tee stdout build.log`.

Comment: Things like this could possibly go into tcllib, but it won't become part of a future Tcl release. It's only 38 lines of pure Tcl code, so you can easily copy it to any project that needs it.

Comment: This is working for my simple test cases, however, as I start to run the EDA tools with it, things get more interesting and I start to have failures.   I have opened another question to deal with this.    See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72371432/redirecting-output-of-tcl-proc-to-file-and-output-like-tee-part-2

Answer (score 0):

You can tee twice for it.

```
close stdout
set fd [open |[list tee my.log | tee /dev/tty ] w]
puts "test"; # both happend in my.log and stdout
```

Comment: This looks like it assumes that TCL is running in a Linux environment.   The problem I have is that the scripting I support runs in both Linux and Windows environments.   I am currently using @Schelte Bron solution.   However, I just wish it were a standard part of TCL and much easier to do for someone with basic level of TCL proficiency.